# Django: Process FileField in model clean method, NOT after save

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    csv = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs')
    rows = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I'm trying to read a CSV file to see how many rows it has and save that to an attribute `rows`. I'm using pandas to read the csv and get the number of lines of the CSV has. I want to do this BEFORE the model saves.

I thought it would work like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    csv = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs')
    rows = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def clean(self):
        self.rows = len(pd.read_csv(self.csv).index)
 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, this returns the following error (which seems to be from pandas):

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

The weird part is it works if I put it AFTER an initial save, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    csv = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs')
    rows = models.IntegerField(default=0)
         
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rows = len(pd.read_csv(self.csv).index)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That seems really weird and inefficient (saving twice I mean).

How can I process the csv like I would after a save BEFORE a save?

And what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you have called `read` on the file somewhere before your `clean` method is called. One fix would be to simply call `open` on the file before passing it to `read_csv`, this as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.open) would either open or reopen the file so it will ensure that the file pointer is at its start:

```
def clean(self):
    self.csv.open(mode='r')
    self.rows = len(pd.read_csv(self.csv).index)
```